# CoreData saving objects earlier than expected

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Match class using Core Data.
In my view controller I create a Match instance in a context.
I'm using and modifying the match object in the controller and then have a button that save the instance in context.
But if I close the application without taping the save button, the Match instance is still saved.

Here's my object declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//(...)

let match = Match(context: AppDelegate.viewContext)

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   }

//(...)
}
```

And here's my save fonction that is called by the button:

```
@IBAction func saveMatch() {   
    try? AppDelegate.viewContext.save()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Look through the rest of your code for where else you call `save()`. If you're using wrappers around Core Data, search for where they call `save()`. You likely have something tied to `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Add a breakpoint on `save()` and see what's calling it.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's it, context.save() is called in the applicationWillTerminate function in AppDelegate, can you post your answer for the tickMark ? @RobNapier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through the rest of your code for where else you call `save()`. If you're using wrappers around Core Data, search for where they call `save()`. You likely have something tied to `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Add a breakpoint on `save()` and see what's calling it.